# Ruby on Rails, convert projectwide single quotes to double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, double-quotes, single-quotes

I wonder if anyone has come up with a shortcut to `correctly` convert ALL single quotes to double quotes in a new rails project. Thank you in advance. I would do that at the end of generating new project with a template.rb

Comment: I would use Rubocop. Configure it to use the quotes you prefer and then run `rubocop -a` to automatically fix all issues.

Comment: @spickermann you seem to indeed _really trust_ rubocop. I would go with `sed` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Indeed, I trust Rubocop more to cover all these encodings, escaping and edge cases. I prefer spending the time to review Rubocop's changes instead of building a correct regexp in sed.

Comment: rubocop it is, I didn't remember it had auto fix capability

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would also use [`rubocop`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) for that:

```
rubocop --safe-auto-correct --only "Style/StringLiterals" .
```

As [`spickermann`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335692/ruby-on-rails-convert-projectwide-single-quotes-to-double-quotes#comment97396617_55335692) suggested